# Token not Stored in LocalStorage

Tags: reactjs, laravel, authentication

So I have a ContextProvider for my React + Laravel Project, however when I click on Login the ACCESS_TOKEN is not getting stored in my LocalStorage

Heres my ContextProvider:

```
import {createContext, useContext, useState} from "react";

const StateContext = createContext({
  currentUser: null,
  token: null,
  notification: null,
  setUser: () => {},
  setToken: () => {},
  setNotification: () => {}
})

export const ContextProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const [token, _setToken] = useState(localStorage.getItem('ACCESS_TOKEN'));
  const [notification, _setNotification] = useState('');

  const setToken = (token) => {
    _setToken(token)
    if (token) {
      localStorage.setItem('ACCESS_TOKEN', token);
    } else {
      localStorage.removeItem('ACCESS_TOKEN');
    }
  }

  const setNotification = message => {
    _setNotification(message);

    setTimeout(() => {
      _setNotification('')
    }, 5000)
  }

  return (
    <StateContext.Provider value={{
      user,
      setUser,
      token,
      setToken,
      notification,
      setNotification
    }}>
      {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
  );
}

export const useStateContext = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

The token gets generated though:
[network screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vnapx.png)

Ive tried to console log the token however even this is not helping.

Also heres my LoginComponent:

```
import {createRef} from "react";
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import axiosClient from "../src/axios-client.js";
import { useStateContext } from "../src/context/ContextProvider.jsx";




export default function LoginComponent() {


    const usernameRef = useRef();
    const passwordRef = useRef();
    const {setUser, setToken} = useStateContext()

    const onSubmit = ev => {
        ev.preventDefault()
    
        const payload = {
          username: usernameRef.current.value,
          password: passwordRef.current.value,
        }
        axiosClient.post('/login', payload)
          .then(({data}) => {
            setUser(data.user)
            setToken(data.token);
            console.log(data.token);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            const response = err.response;
            if (response && response.status === 422) {
             // setMessage(response.data.message)
            }
          })
      }



    return (
        <div className="pt-72 pb-52 mb-6 grid place-items-center">
        <h2 className="text-purple-600 font-bold text-2xl pb-6">Sign in</h2>
        <p>Sign in and start exploring</p>
        <p className="pb-6">the world of films and series</p>
        <div className=" mb-6 w-96">
          <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <input
              ref={usernameRef}
              type="text"
              id="input-group-1"
              className="w-full text-white text-sm rounded-lg pl-10 p-2.5   placeholder-white dark:text-white  focus:ring-purple-600 focus:border-purple-600 dark:focus:ring-purple-600 dark:focus:border-purple-600 border-none"
              placeholder="Username"
              style={{ backgroundColor: "#0B0B0B" }}
            />
    
            <input
              ref={passwordRef}
              type="password"
              id="input-group-2"
              className="w-full  text-white mt-5 text-sm rounded-lg  pl-10 p-2.5   placeholder-white dark:text-white  focus:ring-purple-600 focus:border-purple-600 dark:focus:ring-purple-600 dark:focus:border-purple-600 border-none"
              placeholder="Password"
              style={{ backgroundColor: "#0B0B0B" }}
            />
            
            <div className="flex items-start mb-6 pb-1 mt-6">
              <div className="w-1/2 float-left ">
                <input
                  id="purple-checkbox"
                  type="checkbox"
                  value="0"
                  className="w-4 h-4 text-purple-600 bg-gray-900 border-purple-600 mb-1 rounded focus:ring-purple-600  focus:ring-2  "
                />
                <label
                  htmlFor="purple-checkbox"
                  className="ml-2 text-sm  text-white"
                >
                  Remember Me
                </label>
              </div>
              <div className="w-1/2 text-right float-left">
                <a href="#" className="text-purple-600 text-sm text-right mr-1">
                  Forgot Password ?
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <button
              type="submit"
              className="focus:outline-none text-white bg-purple-700 hover:bg-purple-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-purple-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 mb-2 dark:bg-purple-600 dark:hover:bg-purple-700 dark:focus:ring-purple-900 w-96"
            >
              Login
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
}
```

And heres the Login Page:

```
import Navbar from "../../components/Navbar";
import Footer from "../../components/Footer";
import LoginComponent from "../../components/LoginComponent";

function Login() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar></Navbar>
            <LoginComponent></LoginComponent>
            <Footer></Footer>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Login;
```

Now i wonder myself if i have to wrap the ContextProvider around something.

Comment: Can you share where `setToken` is being called in the context provider children? Have you put breakpoints / logs inside setToken to ensure the function is being called and the token is defined at that moment in the application lifecycle? Have you verified that there is no access_token in local storage in the browser dev tools?

Comment: I have verified that theres no access_token in my localstorage by typing "localStorage" in my console. When u talk about children do i have to wrap my Login in the ContextProvider ?

Comment: In the setToken function did you check by consoling the toke that the function is calling or not ?

Comment: I checked it now no its not getting logged not even null

Comment: Have you checked the axios post request to make sure it’s working? Is it throwing any errors for the network request or entering the then block?

Comment: I get Status Code: 200 OK

However when I look at the auth it tells me Bearer null

Comment: So, you're making a post to '/login' see what you should be getting back any json you're getting back?

Comment: Where can I see that JSON in the network tab ?